# Edit and delete row in HTML table

Tags: python, html, database, flask, crud

I am using flask and have a app.route that takes data submitted in a form and adds it to a database on AWS RDS mysql database.

```
@app.route('/insert',methods = ['post'])    
def insert():

if request.method == 'POST':
    name = request.form['name']
    email = request.form['email']
    gender = request.form['optradio']
    comment = request.form['comment']
    db.insert_details(name,email,comment,gender)
    all_details = db.all_data()
    for all_detail in all_details:
        return render_template('index.html',all_details= all_details)
    details = db.get_details()
```

my db.py:

```
     import pymysql
     import aws_credentials as rds
     conn = pymysql.connect (host='A_RDS_DATABASE.amazonaws.com',
                    user='user',
                    password='Password',
                    database='DB',
                    )

    def insert_details(name,email,comment,gender):
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Details (name,email,comment,gender) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)",(name,email,comment,gender) 
    conn.commit()
```

I have an HTML table that lists all the rows in the database:

```
   <table class="GeneratedTable">
      <thead>
      <tr>

       <th>ID</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Email</th>
       <th>Gender</th>
       <th>Comment</th>

      </tr>
     </thead>

   <tbody>

      <tr>

     {% for row in all_details %}

      <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
      <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
      <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
      <td>{{row[3]}}</td>
      <td>{{row[4]}}</td>

     </tr>

  {% endfor %}
```

I am looking to be able to edit a row and update it in the database and delete a row from the database.

I have tried researching this but I am really stuck trying to find a solution so any help I would be really grateful.

Comment: Your function insert looks wrong with a for loop using a return like that. But I understand that is not the question here. If you want to change the table content I would recommend you look into gridjs flask for it.  You probably need to build the delete using some javascript.

Answer (score 0):

By using the limited information you have provided, I can only help you so much.
The code you are trying to run will not work as you expect with that return statement in the loop.

```
return render_template('index.html', all_details=all_details)
```

Having a return statement inside the loop will effectively break the loop and return the data found at the first index. The best way to handle this would be to send the whole database query result object to the template.

```
all_details = db.all_data()
return render_template('index.html' , all_details=all_details)
```

Then, in you template, process similarly to what you have done. Below I assume that `all_details` returns a dictionary or dict like object.

```
{% for details in all_details %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ details.id }}</td>
  <td>{{ details.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ details.email }}</td>
  <td>{{ details.comment }}</td>
  <td>{{ details.gender }}</td>
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Doing like this will parse the `all_details` object and create a `<tr>` for each item, filling in with your data. In Jinja2 you can also get a dictionary value by using `details['name']`. You might have to test to see which works.

If you plan on using forms, I highly recommend using [flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.x/). This would be a immense help in handling forms and validation.

You basically need to fill in your database data into  `<input>` tags. This will make them editable.

Afterwards, your form should have two submit buttons with different values, such as:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Edit">
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Delete">
```

In your main function you will have to check which was pressed and the run some functions that do what you need.

```
@app.route('/insert',methods = ['post'])    
def insert():

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if request.form['submit_button'] == 'Edit':
        # function that handles the editing of your entry goes here

        if request.form['submit_button'] == 'Delete':
        # function that handles the deletion of your entry goes here
```